# how to set priviledge on port 21 ftp of a host

Tags: server, permissions, ftp

i have a linux hosting working with cakephp.some sites got intrusion/hacked.i used nmap to see the open ports.

i found `21/tcp open ftp` is the port which should be restricted  and not accessible via public.

also i am thinking to restrict /app/config from 777 to 755 and also change `databse.php` file `'login' => 'root',` to `user`.

can i restrict ftp port 21 to set priviledge
if yes, what effect it will have.

how to set priviledge on `ftp port 21` of a host.

other ideas regarding security is also welcomed.

Comment: You only can set fw to allow connections from some ip.

Comment: yeah,how its done.any links for some more ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable fw

```
sudo ufw enable
```

To allow packets from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

To allow packets from network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
```

allow IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx access to port 21 for all protocols

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 21
```

allow IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx access to port 21 using TCP

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 21 proto tcp
```

Comment: To see status command is: sudo ufw status